# Load data after login ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to load data just after login in MVC. I thought to the `ActionFilterAttribute` on top of my root controller (called just after login). It's working fine but I would like to display a waiting message during the load.

What is the better way to implement that?

Comment: What language and/or framework are you talking about? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Title and content question are different. Do you want "Load data after login" or "to display a waiting message during the load." ?

Comment: I want to display a waiting message during the load, which is done after login and before going to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Using following code, you can show any alert message inside `beforeSend`, and hide on `success` or `complete`

```
$('#loginButton').on('click', function () {
            var logindata = { 
                         username: $('#Username').val(),
                         password: $('#Password').val(),
                       };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: logindata,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                       // show your message here..
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                       if (response.isOk == true) 
                       { 
                          //user logged in. show other alert message.
                          window.location = //redirect to home page.
                       }
                       else 
                       {
                          //your custom error occured 
                          alert("Login failed."); 
                       }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    },

                    complete: function(){
                       // You also can check this.
                    }
                });
        });
```